# Can white rice be burned without looking yellow, brown or black?

Tags: rice, boiling, burnt

I try to boil my rice by using just enough water, if I don't cook it in enough water or cook it for too long, the rice will burn.

However, when I burn the rice, I detect it because some of them stick to the pan, and some of the rices close to the once that stick might still taste bad. When cooking with spices, it becomes hard to notice these slightly charred tastes, so my question is as follows, is it possible to burn rice without any indicators like decoloration and stickiness to the cooking surface?

Answer (score 3):

Probably no. Burnt rice will smell burnt and turn black and impact a lot of the rice.

I've burn rice, and it ends by discarding everything.

On the other hand, 
There is a brief moment between cooked rice and burnt rice when the rice on the bottom of the pan is just getting crispy, like the [Paella's socarrat](https://www.sheknows.com/food-and-recipes/articles/807748/the-ultimate-spanish-paella-recipe/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you explain how black rice impacts the rest of the rice? Would you consider the white impacted rice ruined but not burnt? I think it has something to do with the smokes being absorbed by the white rice, not sure.
Thanks